# Vue, passing props stops working when more than one component in the page

Tags: components, vuejs3, undefined, router, vue-props

I have a component, MatchCard.vue in a page called MatchCardView.vue when navigating the website a person can click on a router link in a list item and be directed to MatchCardView.vue where the id associated with that list item is passed to MatchCard.vue as a prop. this all works fine and as expected displaying the proper information, that is until i add any other component to MatchCardView.vue where upon my prop 'mId' suddenly becomes undefined and as a result the subsequent axios call fails.  I have omitted the code for other components I have tried as I have tried as I am fairly sure at this point it can't be an issue with component conflicts.

Mathcard.vue

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import {useInviteStore} from '../Stores/inviteStore';

export default {
  props: ['mId'], // The id from the route is received as a prop
  created() {
    console.log(this.mId); // Log the id to the console for testing
  },

  data() {
      return {
        matches: []
      };
    },
    setup(){
      
    const inviteStore = useInviteStore();
    return { 
      invited: inviteStore.$state.invited, 
      pushInvite: inviteStore.pushInvite, 
      setMatchId: inviteStore.setMatchId
    };
  },
    async mounted() {
      console.log(this.mId);
      await axios.get(`https://localhost:8080/match/matchpost/${this.mId}`, { withCredentials: true })
        .then(response => {
          this.matches = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
        this.push();
    },
    methods:{
      
      push() {
    console.log('push method called'); // for debugging
    console.log(this.setMatchId); // for debugging
    this.setMatchId(this.mId);
      }
    }

}
</script>
```

MatchCardView.vue

```
<script setup>

import MatchCard from '../components/MatchCard.vue';
import FriendsList from '../components/FriendsList.vue';

</script>

<template>
<FriendsList />    
<MatchCard />



</template>
```

router (index.js)

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue';
import MatchCard from '../views/MatchCardView.vue';
import {useAuthStore} from '../Stores/userStore.js';
import axios from 'axios';


const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => import('../views/MatchesView.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/matches',
    name: 'matches',
    component: () => import('../views/MatchesView.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/signin',
    name: 'signin',
    component: () => import('../views/SignIn.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'register',
    component: () => import('../views/RegistrationView.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/profile',
    name: 'profile',
    component: () => import('../views/ProfileView.vue'),
    meta:{
      requiresAuth: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/matchform',
    name: 'matchform',
    component: () => import('../views/MatchPostView.vue'),
    meta:{
      requiresAuth: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/profile/dashboard/:userId',
    name: 'otherProfiles',
    component: () => import('../views/OtherProfilesView.vue'),
    meta:{
      requiresAuth: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/ninjaspotter',
    name: 'ninjaspotter',
    component: () => import('../views/NinjaSpotterView.vue'),
    meta:{
      requiresAuth: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/matchcard',
    name: 'matchcard',
    component: () => import('../views/MatchCardView.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/match/:mId',
    name: 'MatchDetail',
    component: () => import('../views/MatchCardView.vue'),
    props: true,
    meta:{
      requiresAuth: true,
    }
  },
  
];



const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});





router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const auth = useAuthStore();

  // This will refresh the auth state on each route navigation
  await auth.fetchUser();

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
      next();
    } else {
      next('/'); // Redirect to login or home page or whatever you choose
    }
  } else {
    next(); 
  }
});


export default router;
```

- I have tried a number of things such as watching the prop for changes.
- swapping components to ensure that it's not a conflict between components
- using different ways of trying to set the prop

Comment: I had intended to remove the async from mounted() however it works both ways while not fixing the problem.

also here is the router link:

<router-link :to="{ name: 'MatchDetail', params: { mId: match._id } }" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active">

Comment: If you're using a route with params, then you shouldn't be passing a prop to get the id, you should be getting it from the url via the router `this.$route.params`

Answer (score 0):

It seems both links are nav to the MatchCardView.vue, is this a typo or intention?

```
{
    path: '/matchcard',
    name: 'matchcard',
    component: () => import('../views/MatchCardView.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/match/:mId',
    name: 'MatchDetail',
    component: () => import('../views/MatchCardView.vue'),
    props: true,
    meta:{
      requiresAuth: true,
    }
  },
```

Comment: Yes the top one needs removed, that was there from before the current setup and apparently I've forgotten to remove it.